# Loop or function for cohens_d in R

Tags: r, function, loops

May I ask for help with R coding? I have time-series data with 12 time points in wide format in R (each timepoint is a seperate column). I want to calculate cohens_d of the first time point with each of the following time points (2-12). The result should be a data frame, where I have Cohens d and its 95% confidence intervall for each of the 11 comparisons.

By now I just calculated each comparison individually and combined the data frame at the end. But I am sure there is a smarter way with a loop or a function.

```
cohens_d(df$value_1, df$value_2, paired = TRUE) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  mutate(timepoint = 2) -> t2

cohens_d(df$value_1, df$value_3, paired = TRUE) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  mutate(timepoint = 3) -> t3

cohens_d(df$value_1, df$value_4, paired = TRUE) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  mutate(timepoint = 4) -> t4

...

bind_rows(t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way using an example data frame:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(effectsize)

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create the example data frame
df <- data.frame(replicate(12, sample(1:10, replace = TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- paste0("time_", 1:12)

combn(colnames(df), 2, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  map_dfr(~{
    x <- df[[.x[1]]]
    y <- df[[.x[2]]]
    cohens_d(x, y, paired = TRUE) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      mutate(var1 = .x[1], var2 = .x[2])
  }) %>% 
  group_by(group = consecutive_id(var1)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
   Cohens_d    CI  CI_low CI_high var1    var2    group
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <int>
 1  -0.188   0.95 -0.466   0.0930 time_1  time_2      1
 2  -0.0165  0.95 -0.294   0.261  time_2  time_3      2
 3   0.0311  0.95 -0.246   0.308  time_3  time_4      3
 4   0.194   0.95 -0.0868  0.473  time_4  time_5      4
 5  -0.0510  0.95 -0.328   0.227  time_5  time_6      5
 6  -0.308   0.95 -0.591  -0.0230 time_6  time_7      6
 7   0.173   0.95 -0.107   0.451  time_7  time_8      7
 8   0.113   0.95 -0.165   0.391  time_8  time_9      8
 9  -0.0892  0.95 -0.366   0.189  time_9  time_10     9
10  -0.0210  0.95 -0.298   0.256  time_10 time_11    10
11  -0.0407  0.95 -0.318   0.237  time_11 time_12    11
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Unfortunately, I get an error report.

Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `group = consecutive_id(var1)`.
Caused by error in `consecutive_id()`:
! could not find function "consecutive_id"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Please re install dplyr. This feature is new and need dplyr > 1.1.0

Comment: That works, thank you. How can I change the code that I get comparisons from time 1 with the other time points? Time 1 vs. Time 2, Time 1 vs. Time 3 and so on ...

Comment: Solved it already.